# gcc uses wrong linker

Tags: gcc, solaris, ld

My Solaris system has two versions of ld installed

The first belongs to solaris studio:

```
$ /usr/ccs/bin/ld -V
ld: Software Generation Utilities - Solaris Link Editors: 5.10-1.1514
```

And the other one to gcc

```
$ ld -v
GNU ld (GNU Binutils) 2.24
```

I try to use gcc and ld

```
$ which gcc
/usr/bin/gcc
/usr/bin/gcc -> /opt/csw/bin/gcc

$ which ld 
/usr/bin/ld
/usr/bin/ld -> /opt/csw/gnu/ld
```

But when asking gcc which program it uses, it is determined to use the Solaris Studio linker:

```
$ gcc -print-prog-name=ld
/usr/ccs/bin/ld
```

**Question**: how can I get gcc to use the linker at /opt/csw/gnu/ld?

Comment: I would guess that the wrong `ld` appears first in PATH.

Comment: So does the shell, when attempting to run an executable for which the path has not been specified.  What does `which ld` return?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`gcc` is compiled by default to use the Solaris linker. You can override this setting by using the [`LD_ALTEXEC`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26502_01/html/E29030/ld-1.html) environment variable:

```
export LD_ALTEXEC=/opt/csw/gnu/ld
```